# Detecting an iframe is no long displayed from inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am providing a web-component that is displayed inside a iframe. The iframe that loads my component is created like:

```
   this._iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
   this._iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
   this._iframe.src = url;
```

When my component is no longer needed, it is simply cleared by the loader with:

```
this._iframe = null;
```

Now, before my web component is unloaded I should do some clean up. When my component is loaded standalone, this code is working fine for me:

```
if (typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup, false);
}
else if (typeof document.addEventListener != 'undefined') {
    document.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup, false);
}
else if (typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') {
    window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', cleanup);
}

else {
    if (typeof window.onbeforeunload == 'function') {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            cleanup();
        };
    }
    else {
        window.onbeforeunload = cleanup;
    }
}
```

However, the onbeforeunload is never triggered when my component is loaded inside the iframe. Does anyone know how could I detect my web is being unloaded under such circumstances?

Comment: You might need to look at the return value of `cleanup`. Read the notes on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: The problem, as I stated, is that the 'cleanup' method is never called when my web is loaded inside the iframe. It is only called when my web is loaded standalone. I need it it be called also when my web is inside the iframe and the iframe is set to null meaning my component is not displayed anymore.

Comment: _“When my component is no longer needed, it is simply cleared by the loader with: this._iframe = null;”_ - that just removes the reference to the element, that does not necessarily mean it will get “cleared” or destroyed immediately. // Have you tried assigning `about:blank` to the iframe source to clear it, and checked whether that fires beforeunload? Btw, your event handling code that you have shown is applied “inside” the iframe, to its window instance, right?

Comment: In this case it would be useful to provide a working example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also tell us which browsers have this problem.

Comment: I can't change the way the loader unloads my component inside the iframe, so I am stuck with this 'iframe = null' which cannot be change. I suppose that is why the onbeforeunload in my component is not called, because all the loader is doing is just hiding the iframe as you mentioned. All I can do is changing the code inside my component, nothing I can't do in the opener, and yes, this code is inside my component.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ufff... The loader of my small component is a huge web implemented using a library called 'Echo3'. All I do is providing this small component that is loaded inside their web in an iframe. When I asked them how it was loaded they shown me this code I posted here. I think it's not clever unloading it just by simply setting the iframe=null and it may cause a memory leak, but it's not to me to tell whether this is right or wrong, all I have to do is provide the component. I will try to make a working example with their code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests I finally found out how to detect, from inside the iframe's code, that it is being unloaded.

Some considerations:

- For some reason I could not make the onbeforeunload so I had to use onunload.
- Adding events using the 'addEventListener' or 'attachEvent' doesn't work. The events are added when you 'spy' the DOM, but they are not triggered.

With all this, I went for this approach which executes my cleanup method:

```
function checkLoaded(){
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0];
  if(body){
    body.onunload=cleanup;
  } else{ 
    setTimeout(checkLoaded,2000);
  }
}
setTimeout(checkLoaded,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that iframe has it's own window object and also Same Origin policy is applied to iframe, meaning that you cannot control what's inside iframe with scripts that are in your main window. You can communicate between iframe and main window scripts through `postMessage` [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). I don't know if the origin for iframe is the same as your main url though.

Comment: My component, the one that is loaded inside the iframe, and the web that loads it have both the same origin. The problem here is that I cannot modify the 'loader' page to send a message to my component telling it is being unloaded or terminated. The idea is to detect I am being unloaded from inside my component, if that is possible when all they do to unload it is to set the iframe to null in the 'parent' window.